# Unclosed div tag causing Jsoup to duplicate object

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a website however I'm having some issues because of divs not being closed resulting in duplicate results. At the link bellow you can see some sample html with the issue I'm trying to fix.

https://try.jsoup.org/~ZgrRams0ZaoOWw73sGDrV7Zz0iU

What would be the best way around this?

**Edit**: Bellow is a quick code snippet that shows my problem:

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class test {

    private static final String HTML = "<div class=\"content-item\"><div class=\"col-md-9\" style="
            + "\"padding-left: 0px;\"><h2 class=\"child-debate-title hs_6bDepartment\">"
            + "Wales</h2></div><div class=\"content-item\">"
            + "<div class=\"col-md-9\" style=\"padding-left: 0px;\">"
            + "<h2 class=\"child-debate-title hs_8Question\">Welsh Language</h2>"
            + "</div>";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
        Elements elements = doc.select("div.content-item");
        System.out.println(elements.html());
    }
}
```

The output is the following:

```html
<div class="col-md-9" style="padding-left: 0px;">
 <h2 class="child-debate-title hs_6bDepartment">Wales</h2>
</div>
<div class="content-item">
 <div class="col-md-9" style="padding-left: 0px;">
  <h2 class="child-debate-title hs_8Question">Welsh Language</h2>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9" style="padding-left: 0px;">
 <h2 class="child-debate-title hs_8Question">Welsh Language</h2>
</div>
```

I need to get the content-item div as content for other parts of the page is nested inside this div.

Comment: What is the problem? Post your Java code that you have tried.

Comment: The problem is that the second div is duplicated on the first line result

Comment: As you can see in try.jsoup.org, there are not duplicated elements, the problem is that "content-item" are in different levels, one inside the another, and you are selecting and printing both, the parent and the child. (seeing the child twice). Just try `doc.select("div.col-md-9");`